# Multi-arm bandit with partial observability

Tags: multiarmed-bandit

I've been trying to find a formulation of the multi-arm bandit problem with partial observibility. The motivation is that it may be hard to identify that one arm is different from another in some circumstances, but given observations given after choosing an arm, it would be possible to distinguish between arms by maintaining belief over which arms are which.

Does this exist in the multi-arm bandit problem community?